# Is an iOS static library compiled with GCC 4.2 compatible with LLVM in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc

I'm developing iOS apps and I've just upgraded my Xcode to 4.2.
I see that the GCC 4.2 compiler is no longer available.

Can I still link my static library, which was previously compiled with GCC 4.2?  Would it cause any problems?

Answer (score 1):

Very probably yes. ABI conventions don't change much. However, since it is *your* static library, I assume you still have its source code. Then it is better to recompile in with a recent compiler (like GCC *4.6*) and with `-Wall` flag. GCC compiler is improving from version to version (particularily since 4.2 which is several years old), in compliance to language standards, in diagnostic abilities (better warnings), and in optimization.

Comment: Thanks :) I do have the source, but this library is also available to others. I want to make sure that it'll be supported both with the current version and with older versions. Will it be supported in both cases (while it's still compiled with GCC 4.2) ?

Comment: Probably yes, but I cannot be sure, and I suggest you to try by yourself.

Comment: As a note, Apple has abandoned the GCC compiler in favor of LLVM, for several reasons.  This is why GCC is no longer available as a compiler for the Xcode IDE.  To get GCC to build and target their platforms, Apple had heavily patched the 4.2 version and hadn't invested the effort to bring these patches forward to the newer versions.  That's why the last version of GCC that was used in Xcode was 4.2.  You're right, though, binary compatibility is maintained with static libraries built using GCC 4.2 in the new LLVM-using version of Xcode.